# Can't access object inside object using an event handler

Tags: javascript, object, dom-events

I have two functions that I use as classes: `Person` and `Eye`.
`Person` creates an `Eye` object in itself. Later on I try to access the eye object created, with an event handler for whenever the user clicks on the web page.

```
function Eye(){
   this.color="Green";
}


function Person() {

   this.name="John";
   this.eye = new Eye();
   //eye=this.eye; // uncomment and everything works!

   document.addEventListener("click", function(){
      console.log(name); // This works

      console.log(eye);  // This doesn't work

   })

}

var person= new Person();
```

Why doesn't this work? Making a second variable `eye` seems to solve the issue but I have no clue why..

Comment: *"Making a second variable `eye` seems to solve the issue but I have no clue why."*: Because with that you are creating a global variable.

Comment: No. `this` is an object which at that moment only exists inside the function and `eye` is a property of that object. `this` is a special variable in JavaScript, have a look at the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because "eye" is not a variable, it's a property of an object. You're doing nothing to tell JavaScript what object to look at.

You'll have to save the value of `this` in another local variable:

```
function Person() {
  this.name="John";
  this.eye = new Eye();
  var person = this;
```

Then you can use that in the event handler:

```
    console.log(person.eye);
```

Comment: Is it possible to get this of Object Constructor without saving value of this in another local variable ???

Comment: @Givi no.  The value of `this` is set upon each function invocation (including the invocation of your event handler). It's not an inherent property of any object.  There are other ways of making sure that the right value of `this` is available, but they all amount to the same basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(name);
    console.log(eye);
});
```

In this context, `name` refers to the `name` property of the window object, since you didn't specify the object off of which you wanted to access it. `window.name` just so happens to return `"result"` on my implementation. And ogging `eye` won't work because `eye` has not been defined as a variable.

To fix this, use a variable to store the reference to the current object *outside* the event function and use it inside.

```
var ref = this;

document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(ref.name);
    console.log(ref.eye);
});
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> John
> Eye { color: "Green" }
> ```

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/TUEgB/)